# Open string as correct filetype in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In an app I'm writing, I've downloaded a file as a string. I have the file name and extension, so I know what type of file it is, but it's downloaded as a string of wingdings and such. How do I convert it to the right type and open it on Android?

I'm writing the app in Xamarin forms using C#. Is it much different to do it in iOS?

```
    async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Publication p = (Publication)e.SelectedItem;
        Debug.WriteLine(p);
        if (p.folderID.Equals("-1"))
        {
            string resp = await post(p.docNum);
            //Downloaded file is "resp"
            //Open file here, could be pdf, etc. Filename and extension are 
            //properties of Publication "p"

        } else
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new PublicationsPage(p.folderID));
        }
    }


    private async Task<String> post(string id)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dir = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dir.Add("LoginID", App.user.login_id);
        dir.Add("docID", id);
        var jsonReq = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dir);
        Debug.WriteLine("req: " + (String)jsonReq);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonReq, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("urlLink.com", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseString;
    }
```

Comment: instead of telling us that you've "downloaded a file as a string", why don't you show us the ACTUAL CODE that you wrote to do this?

Comment: `I have the file name and extension, so I know what type of file it is,`. But you will not tell us? Any reason?

Comment: if the post() method is what actually does the download, then it would make sense to share that code, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data):

```
var myObject = new MyType();
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resp));
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(myObject.GetType());
myObject = ser.ReadObject(ms) as MyType;
ms.Dispose();
```

Out of scope: Define MyType and "open" myObject.